# Parsing nested json values using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have seen many examples on parsing data, but it is still confusing me.

I am using gson to parse json data in java.

Here is my json data--

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "login",
"data": [
    {
        "value1" : "value1",
        "vaue2": {
            "name": "myname"
             },
        "value 3": "value 3",
    }]
}
```

I want to retrieve "value 1" and "value2".

I have created pojo classes. But when I am trying to retrieve the values using these statements it is returning empty value.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Datum datum = gson.fromJson(json_string,Datum.class);
 String code = datum.getValue1();
```

My model class:

```
public class Datum {
    private String value1;
    @SerializedName("value1")
    /////more code

public String getValue1() {
    return value1;
}
```

But when I try to parse values for "success" and "message" as above, it is fine. Problem is when Im trying to parse nested values.

Comment: having the annotation *after* the field declaration will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create objects for nested structures

```
public class Datum
   @SerializedName("value1")
   private String value1;

   @SerializedName("data")
   private Data[] data;


public class Data
   private String value;
```

Comment: yes I have added that too(did not mention in the que though). But how do we parse a particular field?

Comment: once your pojo gets populated successfully, you can access fields using object.
    `
    datum.getData()[0].value1
    `

you can iterate over Data obj as per your requirement